# Proving a linear bounded operator invertible

Tags: functional-analysis

*I am not familiar with functional analysis at all. I apologize beforehand if there is any conceptual mistake. The situation is as follows:

Let H be a real Hilbert space, suppose I have a bounded linear operator $T: H \to H$ such that there exists $m > 0$ satisfies $ \lvert \langle Tx, x \rangle \rvert ≥ m\lVert x \rVert ^2$ (*) for any $x \in H$. Show that $T$ is invertible.

I have two outlines of proof in my hand:

(i)
We wish to find an operator $S$ such that $S \circ T = id$. So a natural idea is to plug in $Sx$ and try it out. One obtains $ \lvert \langle Tx, Sx \rangle \rvert ≥ m\langle Sx, Sx \rangle. $

On the other hand, one uses the boundedness property and plugs in $Sx$ again one obtains
$ \lVert TSx \rVert \le M \lVert Sx \rVert$

Compare the equations one forces $M = m = 1$.

(ii) One could prove $T$ is in fact a bijection. The injection part is easy by the inequality in the assumption. I haven't found a good way to prove surjection.

Now, may I ask:

Are both (i) and (ii) valid? Is there deep math behind the seemingly harmless inequality (*), as I would say invertibility is rather unexpected...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $y$ is orthogonal to the range then $\langle Ty,y\rangle=0.$ Hence $y=0$ which implies that the range is dense. The assumption implies $$\|Tx\|\|x\|\ge|\langle Tx,x\rangle |\ge m\|x\|^2\quad $$ Therefore $$\|Tx\|\ge m\|x\|\quad (*)$$ Hence the range is closed. Thus the operator is surjective. It is also injective by $(*).$
Next $(*)$ gives $$ m\|T^{-1}y\| \le \|TT^{-1}y\|=\|y\|$$ The latter implies that the inverse is bounded with norm less or equal $m^{-1}.$